# arm assembly mutex strex, ldrex

Tags: assembly, arm, mutex

firstly thank you for watching my question and reply previously.

I'm making an os like software on banana-pi m1.

This platform is dual cortex a-7.

and also i'm implementing a mutex like below.

```
.global lock_mutex
lock_mutex:
    ldr     r1, =UNLOCKED
1:  ldrex   r2, [r0]
    cmp     r2, r1

    wfene                           @ wfe if locked

    read_cp32(r1, MPIDR)            @ MPIDR (ARMv7 only)
    strexne r2, r1, [r0]            @ Trying to lock
    cmpne   r2, #1                  @ if failed to lock acquire
    beq     1b                      @ branch to before 1 label if fail to lock

    dmb
    bx      lr

.global unlock_mutex                @ in the case of unlock, 
                                  @there's no need to check the status of lock
unlock_mutex:
    ldr     r1, =UNLOCKED
    dmb
    str     r1, [r0]                @ clear the lock
    dmb 
    sev                             @ sending the event to other processors that is wfe status
    bx      lr
```

in the line of "ldrex   r2, [r0]" this instruction, nothing happen and seems cpu die.

is there any advice before use ldrex & strex instruction

Comment: You need to have caches enabled for this to work.  See: [ARM infocenter](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0008a/ch01s03s02.html).  Also, you need to initialize the `[r0]` memory (full/empty/valid) and the memory needs to be in cache.  You could use a `pld` instruction. *in the line of "ldrex r2, [r0]" this instruction, nothing happen and seems cpu die.*... so if `r0` is garbage (passed in to `lock_mutex`), then this will happen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My mistake was that i didn't know i had to enable the cache before execute that kind of instruction. Really thank you!!